# How are the questions in IQ tests formulated?

Tags: intelligence, iq

I would like to know how psychologists come up with the questions they include in an IQ test and how they know that those questions will accurately measure intelligence? How has it been proved that IQ tests do indeed work?

Comment: @Christian I can see that you feel that iq tag would be useful. Please discuss issue in [meta](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/) before engaging in mass retagging. If the community approves of this, only then do it. There is an argument that the iq tag is not required. i.e., many questions tagged intelligence are about iq; having both tags will mean that many people using the iq tag will fail to apply the broader discipline tag.

Comment: This is [how psychologists design an IQ test](http://www.neuroscientia.com/2017/07/designing-iq-test.html) step-by-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alfred Binet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Binet) developed the first intelligence measurement with some psychological validity. He asked general psychological questions from groups discovered by [Spearman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Spearman) of varying difficulty based in the (not yet discovered) concept of [fluid intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_and_crystallized_intelligence) to children. Some did well some did not. This led to an age standardized test called the [Stanford-Binet Intelligence Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford%E2%80%93Binet_Intelligence_Scales). Which essentially was problems of varying difficulty tested on many different children of diverse backgrounds to create a baseline. Results were grouped by age in order to give a predicted evaluation of common performance ability.

[IQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient) tests do not work as a measurement of success and no one thinks that they do. They do work as a measurement of specifically identified and labeled cognitive ability. They are more useful psychologically in identifying cognitive problems to give treatments or accommodations than providing congratulatory measures to those who perform well.